# Getting free dyno-hours remaining programmatically

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

Is it possible via the API or some other form to display the remaining hours left on my free run-time in Heroku?

In my case, I'd like to have it display on my discord bots about page as an incentive to gather support for its development and management.

Comment: Hey Sexi Exi, could you figure out a way to do this programatically?

Answer (score 1):

Not familar with Heroku at all, but according to [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours):

```
heroku ps -a <app name>
```

Can be used to get the amount of hours left.